# inserting a date and time in flask from form for multiple timezones

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am making an app that schedules appointments for a person giving lessons to other people, many of those people are located in different time-zones than the lesson giver.

There are 2 people who can view any given appointment, the user who created and the superuser, who gives the lesson.

How do I insert the time and date into my db from a form in my flask template so that I can save the time and date a user wants a lesson, and display it in the timezone of the current viewer?

I think the display part would probably be done using moment.js but I can't figure out the insert.

I am using flask with sqlalchemy to interact with my postgresql db.

Comment: You want to save the selected time of the lesson that represents time in timezone of the person that will get the lessons in the database?

Comment: I guess it would probably be best to save it as UTC and convert it on display.

Comment: I used `getTimezoneOffset()` from javascript `Date` class ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)) to get timezone offset from UTC time. You can then also pass the timezone offset data from form to Flask backend.